# I need Plan of Attack! Please help

Tags: boot, grub2, mbr

I need for someone to help me creating a plan of attack ; )

**Purpose**: Setting up dual booting = Windows 8.1 + Ubuntu 13.10.

**Present status**:
Both OSs are installed in a different hard disks, with messed up booting files.

**How did I get here** (short version): 
Days ago I had unplugged the Windows hard disk from the motherboard in order to reinstall Ubuntu, and keep things simple while doing it. It all went well, I ran Ubuntu successfully for about 5 days, after a good number of tweaks here and there I very happy with what I've got. My next step was to fix the Windows booting files.
Unfortunately I didn't think of unplugging the Ubuntu hard disk this time : ( As you may imagine, this messed up GRUB. 
I was able to fix the MBR with the Win8 Repair startup USB key, using: ''bootrec /fixmbr'', but the following command failed: ''bootrec /fixboot'', it replied: ''The volume does not contain a recognized file system. Please make sure that all required file system drivers are loaded and that the volume is not corrupted''. 
Additionally, I proceded to try: ''bcdedit /set {default} device partition=c'', but I got this: ''The boot configuration data store could not be opened. The system cannot find the file specified'' 
It was after this that my GRUB got messed up.

**Where to now?**
I have Boot Repair Disk, Super Boot Manager, and EasyBCD. Also a USBlive with Ubuntu 13.10.

At least for now, I don`t need actual details, but rather a clear layout of steps to take. Please consider what I want to accomplish, and where I am.
Example: Start by 1. Repairing the Windows booting files, successfully boot into Windows. Then 2. Do the same for Ubuntu: fix GRUB, then boot from a USBlive to run Super Boot Manager to setup the dual boot.
The above was just an example, and if anything a wild speculation of what's ahead.

Thanks a trillion guys!

JDL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Mukul's answer will work, it's quite a long process.  I think windows should boot fine if you just switch which MBR your BIOS points to and then do a smart repair of grub:

1. Enter your BIOS settings and change your primary drive to the
   windows drive.
2. Verify windows now boots
3. Use Boot Repair Disk to reinstall grub

Comment: Thank you kindly vurtualxtc for your reply :)
Could you pls now advise me on how exactly to fix the Windows 8 booting files? Since the Win8 Repair Disk failed to do it itself with the 'automatic repair option', and the 'bootrec /fixboot' failed...

Comment: Every BIOS is different, you best bet is to read you computers manual, call the manufacture of the computer for support on how to change bios settings, or try and google it.  Aside from windows errors; as my girlfriend likes to tell tells me "I don't do windows"   ...but you might have some luck on superuser.stackexchange.com

Comment: Got it! I appreciate your reply anyway. The BIOS settings won't be a problem. Is namely fixing the booting files that I need to figure out :(
I'll check on superuser.stackexchange.com as you suggested.

Comment: I'm back, unfortunately :-(

Comment: did switching the primary drive in your BIOS allow you to boot windows?

Answer (score 0):

Windows is very notorious for not allowing other non-windows OSes to exist on the same computer.

The steps would be:

1. Boot your computer into Windows setup CD.
2. Repair your boot process and MBR.
3. Once you verify that you can log into Windows, launch Ubuntu install.
4. Ubuntu will recognize that there is Windows and install Grub. It may also ask you to choose the default OS.
5. After Ubuntu is installed you can have a dual-boot PC.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your reply Mukul. I will keep it in mind should I give up repairing GRUB. Then I will re-install Ubuntu as you suggest.